# MVC: When using Kendo().Window to load PartialView, getting an error "The resource cannot be found"

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I'm using modal `Kendo().Window()` to load a `Partial View` on a button click.

I have a main View, let's say View1 containing the button, the code to display a window where the `Partial View` containing the `Kendo().Grid` will be loaded, and a `javascript` function which opens the window:

This is what I have on my View1:

This is the button:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
            .Name("btnSubmit")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button"})
            .Icon("k-icon k-i-file-txt")
            .Content("View Details")
            .Events(e => e.Click("DisplayDetailedView"))
)
```

This is a window to display a content of a `PartialView`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
            .Name("ReportData")
            .Title("Details Report")
            .LoadContentFrom("RedirectToView", "MyController")
            .Modal(true)
            .Visible(false)
            .Width(800)
            .Height(375)
            .Position(p => p.Top(100).Left(800))
)
```

And this is a `javascript` function to open a window:

```
function DisplayDetailedView() {
    var w = $("#ReportData").data("kendoWindow");
    w.open();
}
```

My `Partial View` has a Kendo().Grid that calls a method from a controller to get populated with a data:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Report)
  .......
  .DataSource(ds => ds
      .Ajax()
      .Read(read => read.Action("GetReport","MyController", Model))

)
```

When I'm loading View1, the method that is supposed to be called on Grid initialization, gets called and I'm getting the error saying"

> "The resource cannot be found.
>
> HTTP 404.  The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL:/MyController/GetReport"

Looks like, the page is trying to render my `Kendo().Window`, calls `RedirectToView` in controller from `.LoadContentFrom` event of the window to redirect to my `Partial View` with the Grid

The functionality used to work with bootstrap modal approach, when I did not use `Kendo().Window` inside of the View1, but used an `Ajax` call on the button click that called `RedirectToView`method:

```
function ShowReversalsDetailedView() {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/MyController/RedirectToView/",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                $(".modal-content").html(result);
            }
        })
}
```

However, I need to change it to a `Kendo().Window()`

How can I fix it?

Comment: From your error it seems that you problem is related to the grid right? I mean If you remove your grid and just write something in the partial view does this open correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First, RedirectToView should be returning a partial view - not redirecting to it.

Assuming that is the case, try loading your content when you open your window. So first, remove `.LoadContentFrom("RedirectToView", "MyController")` from the window declaration.

Then in your javascript function:

```
function DisplayDetailedView() {
    var w = $("#ReportData").data("kendoWindow");
    w.refresh({
        url: '@Url.Action("RedirectToView", "MyController")'
    });
    w.open();
}
```

I would also change your ajax call to use @Url.Action. I am confused though why you would be calling RedirectToView here? Is it a POST or is it returning a partial or is it redirecting? Redirecting would be bad - you need to do that client side.

```
function ShowReversalsDetailedView() {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '@Url.Action("RedirectToView", "MyController")',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                $(".modal-content").html(result);
            }
        })
}
```

See https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/methods/refresh