# After loading my Partial View via Ajax call more than once, my Kendo Window looses closable:true

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Kendo Window where I load a partial view via an Ajax-Call as content.

When first loading the the Partial View, everything is ok. (The Kendow Window is closable, like I want).

But when I close it and again click the button that opens that Window & loads the Partial View into it, the window is **not** closable anymore.

(I set `closable: true` in javascript but it can't be that the partial view causes the js-file to disappear from the DOM?)

index.html

```
<head>   @Scripts.Render("~/index.js")</head><body>
<div id="myWin"></div>                    ...</body>
```

index.js

```
function openWindow() {   
            var myWindow=$("#myWin");
            myWindow.kendoWindow({
                width: "1200px",
                height: "500px",
                title: "Title",
                modal: true,
                closeable: true, //////
                open: onOpen
            });
            $(".k-window-title").css('line-height', '30px');
            $(".k-window-action").css('visibility', "hidden");
            function onOpen(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: general.createMethodUrl("", "MyController", "MyWindowContent"),   //partial view 
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function (result) {
                        getMyWindow().html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            myWindow.data("kendoWindow").open().center();
            tempWindow = myWindow.data("kendoWindow");
}
```

MyController.cs

```
  public ActionResult MyWindowContent()
        {
            return PartialView("PartialViews/MyPv");
        }
```

MyPv.cshtml

```
<head><script>...</script></head> @*<body>*@  DIV WITH KENDO GRID HERE @*</body>*@
```

Comment: Without any code I can only guess. Do you get any errors in the JavaScript debug console? My first hunch would be that the second time you open the window, some conflicts break something.

Comment: I don't get any errors and every other interaction works fine. 
It also continous being modal (and modal:true is setted right before closable:true)

Comment: Show the code where you define and open the window.

Comment: done @SteveGreene

Comment: Minor issue, but I don't see closeable in the [window api](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window), but it does exist in the [dialog api](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog/configuration/closable) as `closable`. I think your issue is probably more related to AJAX loading wrecking your events. What I do is define my window and call a function that opens it which uses `refresh` with a `url` parameter. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714134/mvc-when-using-kendo-window-to-load-partialview-getting-an-error-the-resour).

Comment: Although it seems to work, but it looks a bit strange anyway: You are defining `onOpen` within `openWindow`. And a partial view should not contain any `html`, `body` and so on, since it is directly included in the DOM. See https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/window/overview#load-content-through-ajax for more details.

Comment: oh that's a point @SteveGreene